# CHtml::link просит еще 1 параметр

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php echo CHtml::linkTag($post->tags,array('material/seachtag')); ?>
```

Получаю:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Что еще нужно `LinkTag`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл как бы [намекает](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#linkTag-detail)

Читайте маны. А вообще второй агрумент у вас массив вместо строки